# Smarter Electric Pair

Tags: electric-pair-mode

I like electric pairing for things like...

```
someJavascript(function() {  });
```

Where it automatically pairs { with {) etc.

However, it infuriates me when I have

```
someFunction();
```

and I want to turn that into

```
wrapped(someFunction());
```

It comes out as:

```
wrapped()someFunction();
```

so I have to break my rhythm and delete the `)`.

Comment: You might want to look into [`smartparens`](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens).

Comment: On #1, you can select `someFunction()` as the region and then type `(`.

Comment: Could you break your second question off into a second post, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to deal with this is to use structural editing commands. So, instead of thinking "delete the character, add it at the end", I think something like "wrap the paren pair around the next token".

One library that does this is called [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens), and the function is `#'sp-forward-slurp-sexp`. Starting with this text (with the pipe marking point):

```
wrapped(|)someFunction();
```

Calling `#'sp-forward-slurp-sexp` results in:

```
wrapped(|someFunction)();
```

And a second time in:

```
wrapped(someFunction());
```

Comment: Consider using `sp-slurp-hybrid-sexp`. It does the right thing in this context.

Comment: That's interesting. Is there a downside to using `sp-slurp-hybrid-sexp`? The documentation seems to indicate that the only loss of functionality is that it doesn't support prefix arguments the way `sp-forward-slurp-sexp` does.

Comment: There is also no equivalent barfing command, and it only operates to the right. Other than that, I'm unaware of any shortcomings.

Comment: It would be great if  electric-pair support `sp-forward-slurp-sexp` function.